# is it possible to return value from method enclosed in the lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

i encounter a line java book which state that "when a return statement occurs within a lambda expression,it simply cause a return from the lambda.It does not cause an enclosing method to return".

Does above statement mean we cant return value from method enclosed in the lambda expression.
i couldn't find any example so created a dummy program which wont compile.

```
Numeric num=(n)->{               // assume interface Numeric{  int func(int n); }

        int a=5;

      int result=n/a;

     resultMethod(n)   // assume int resultMethod(int a) is method.
{
return n;
}

return result;
}
System.out.println(num.func(12));
```

Comment: check n == null not n.equals("Null")..

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(  n.equals("Null"))
 {

 }
```

This will check the entered value is Null text. This will work true if you enter Null as text in the promt. If you want to check n is NULL try the below code

```
if(n == null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example :

```
public static void main() {
    funcInt fi = (n) -> {
        return n;
    }
    System.out.println("This will be executed");
}
```

In above example, the print statement will get printed.

The return statement inside lambda expression, won't lead to return of main without printing the statement.